# Strange behaviour when applying fn:data to info-node

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

When I run the following xquery in MarkLogic":

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $envelope := <envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services"> 
                                <info>hello</info>
                             </envelope>

return fn:data($envelope/es:info)
```

I receive this error:

[1.0-ml] XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT: fn:data(hello) -- Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content

Strangely, when I rename the info-node to info1 for instance the code works as expected:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $envelope := <envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
                         <info1>hello</info1>
                     </envelope>

return fn:data($envelope/es:info1)
```

result is: hello (as expected)

Can someone explain this black magic to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic tries to retrieve a typed value from your data when using `fn:data()`. MarkLogic will look for an appropriate schema for that purpose. Since you are using the entity-services namespace, it will look for the entity-services schema. This schema has a particular definition of the `info` element (as correctly mentioned by Michael), which doesn't match the way you use it.

Using `fn:string()` instead of `fn:data()` is usually more robust, since it will by-pass data type checking. Using an element name which is not defined in the entity-services schema is gives you a quick fix that will work now, but it might be tricky to guarantee it will work in future as well.

Personally, I'd advice to use the entity-services namespace as intended. If you need to put in additional elements, put them in a different namespace, with or without an accompanying schema. Or, simply drop the namespace entirely.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It wasn't clear from the marklogic documentation, that fn:data() actually searched for schema's. And actually we were using xdmp:hash64() which uses fn:data underwater, so in our case the solution was to use fn:string(xdmp:hash64($variable))

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because the schema `entity-type.xsd` defines the elements as non-mixed:

```
<xs:complexType name="InfoType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="es:title"/>
      <xs:element ref="es:version"/>
      <xs:element ref="es:base-uri" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element ref="es:description" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="info" type="es:InfoType"/>
```

A element can be of mixed content if it has a `mixed="true"` attribute. Because you cannot change the schema in this case, i'd try using `string()`.

```
declare namespace es = "http://marklogic.com/entity-services";

let $envelope := <envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services"> 
                    <info>
                      <title>hello</title>
                      <version>1.0</version>
                    </info>
                 </envelope>

return $envelope/es:info/string()
```

This gives you `hello1.0` as a result if this is what you wanted.

Your example with `info1` works, because this element is not defined in the schema (and thus wouldn't be a valid xml).

Answer (score 1):

Because fn:data() has potential interactions with schemas, consider using fn:string() to get the text of an element as a string.